# Sufficient conditions for a graph to be able to be represented by the join of two graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for sufficient conditions for a simple graph to be able to be represented by the join of two other simple graphs both of which have order greater than or equal to $2$.

Some specific questions would be:

> 1. What is number of edges in a graph needed to guarantee a graph can be represented by the join of two graph both with order greater than or equal to $2$.
> 2. What does the minimum degree of each vertex need to be to guarantee a graph can be represented by the join of two graph both with order greater than or equal to $2$.

Comment: well I have tried searching the internet to find any articles on this subject but I haven't been able to find any. As far as my specific questions go they were not of particular importance to me these were just a couple of sufficient conditions that I thought of off the top of my head that could be good but I had not put much effort into finding their answers. I am really just searching for a good collection of theorems that give sufficient conditions for a graph to be able to be represented by the join of two other simple graphs both of which have order greater than or equal to 2 .

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ have $n$ vertices, where $n\ge 4$. Say that a graph has property $J$ if it’s the join of two graphs each of order at least $2$.

For the first question, if we start with $K_n$ and remove $n-2$ of the edges incident at a fixed vertex $v$, the resulting graph does not have property $J$. Thus, the minimum number of edges required to guarantee that $G$ has property $J$ is at least $$\binom{n}2-(n-2)+1=\binom{n}2-n+3\;.$$ And in fact this does the trick.

Suppose that $G$ has at least $\binom{n}2-n+3$ edges. Then $\overline{G}$, the complement of $G$, has at most $n-3$ edges, and the largest component of $\overline{G}$ has at most $(n-3)+1=n-2$ vertices. Let $V_0$ be the set of vertices in the largest component of $\overline{G}$, and let $V_1$ be the remaining set of vertices. Then $|V_0|,|V_1|\ge 2$, and $\overline{G}$ has no edge between $V_0$ and $V_2$, so $G$ is the join of graphs on $V_0$ and $V_1$ and has property $J$.

So far I have only a partial answer to the second question, one showing that a fairly large bound is required . Suppose that $G$ is the join of $H$ and $K$. If $u$ and $v$ are vertices of $H$ and $K$, respectively, then we must have $\deg_Gu+\deg_Gv\ge n$. The weakest uniform minimum degree condition on $G$ that ensures this is requiring that $\deg_Gu\ge\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil$ for each vertex $u$ of $G$. However, this is insufficient to ensure that $G$ has the desired property.

For a counterexample, let $n=2m$, and let $H$ and $K$ be copies of $K_m$ with vertices $u_0,\ldots,u_{m-1}$ and $v_0,\ldots,v_{m-1}$, respectively. Let $G$ be the disjoint union of $H$ and $K$ together with the edges $\{u_k,v_k\}$ for $k=0,\ldots,m-1$. Then $\deg_Gw=m=\frac{n}2$ for each vertex $w$ of $G$, but it’s easy to check that if $m\ge 3$, then $G$ does not have property $J$.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I would up vote your answer if I had the reputation points to do it but this is a new account.  Do you happen to know of any other sufficient conditions for a graph to be able to be represented by the join of two other simple graphs both of which have order greater than or equal to 2 or perhaps where I would be able to find some?

Comment: @Pete: You’re welcome. I don’t, I’m afraid. I’m very far from being a graph theorist, so that’s all from first principles; it’s entirely possible that graph theorists would have more to say or pointers to literature.

Comment: I suspect your partial answer to second question. Consider $H$ as $P_6$, path graph on $6$ vertices and $K$ as $K_2$. Then there is a vertex of degree $3$ in $G$. So....

Comment: In fact, taking $H$ as $P_n$ for a large $n$ and $K$ as $K_2$...I don't think minimum degree of u(G) will depend on $n$.

Comment: @Sry: You appear to have misunderstood the question. The problem is to find a minimum condition on the degrees that **guarantees** that the graph has property $J$. Of course there will also be graphs with property $J$ that fail to meet that condition.

Comment: Oh! my fault...you are absolutely correct. Thank you for pointing.

Comment: @Sry: That’s okay; you’re welcome.